# Sun Grid Engine, force one job per node

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, sungridengine, starcluster

I am running many repeats of the same job using numpy on a cluster that uses sun grid engine to distribute jobs (starcluster).  Each of my nodes has 2 cores (c3.large on AWS).  So say I have 5 nodes, each with 2 cores.

The matrix operations in numpy are able to use more than one core at a time.  What I'm finding is that SGE will send out 10 jobs to run at once, each job using a core.  This is causing longer runtimes for the jobs.  Looking at htop, it looks like the two jobs on each core are fighting over resources.

How can I tell qsub to distribute 1 job per node.  So that when I submit my jobs, only 5 will be running at once, not 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: Add a complex values to your cluster. Run

```
qconf -mc
```

Add a line like

```
exclusive        excl      INT         <=    YES         YES        0        0
```

Step 2: For each of your nodes, define a value for that complex value.

```
qconf -rattr exechost complex_values exclusive=1 <nodename>
```

Here we set exclusive to 1. Then, when you launch jobs, request "1" of that resource. Eg.:

```
qrsh -l exclusive=1 <myjob>
```

If you were willing to have 2 jobs per node, you could define that value to 2 at step 2.

EDIT: This is how to configure it per node. You could have done it for the entire cluster in step 1 by setting the value into the "default" column to 1.

Comment: "EDIT: This is how to configure it per node. You could have done it for the entire cluster in step 1 by setting the value into the "default" column to 1."   This is exactly what I want to do.  I tried that, but it still kicked off 10 jobs at once, instead of 5.  Do I need to run the "excl" command?

Comment: Then when launching jobs, do: "qrsh -l exclusive=1 qsub -e ..." like that..?

Comment: No, qsub and qrsh are both tools to launch jobs. qsub detaches, qrsh is interactive. So you can just replace qrsh by qsub in the example.

Comment: Maybe the default is not working. Try to set it per node then with the qconf -rattr command.